# How to log into jenkins I don't remember credentials MACOS

Tags: macos, jenkins

I recently downloaded jenkins for mac and upon setting it up in local host I clicked the wrong button and it gave the username admin and I don't know what the password is.

> docker run   --rm   -u roo  -p 8080:8080   -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock   -v "$HOME":/home   jenkinsci/blueocean

Thats the command I entered and now it takes me straight to the login page where it asks for my username and password.

I already looked for .jenkins or JENKINS_HOME and all jenkins folders and can't find a single thing. Where should I look?

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it keeps taking me straight to the login page.

Answer (score 4):

You can temporarily turn off authentication, set your password, then re-enable authentication. Assuming you have jenkins' home as a local volume:

```
  $ vi <JENKINS_HOME_VOLUME_ROOT>/config.xml
  <useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

Restart your container. Be sure to set back to `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` when done

Comment: Did it ask you for login credentials after making the XML change? If so docker exec into the container and cat $JENKINS_HOME/config.xml to confirm its actually changed. In addition have you tried the @towel's suggestion: $JENKINS_HOME/secrets/initialAdminPassword ?

Comment: Found my own solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already changed the admin password you may find it under `$JENKINS_HOME/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

Comment: im putting that in as the password. with admin as my username. Still not working.

Comment: What users do you see under the users directory in Jenkins?

Comment: Found my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

Found my own solution. Went to /usr/local/bin and found the jenkins file and i doubled clicked it and it reset everything and generated the .jenkins folder I was missing. It brought me back to the Setup Wizard and I'm good to go.Now I just have to double click this file each time I want to run it.